# Usage of "even when" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Does the meaning of this sentence change if “even when” is placed in the beginning? Removing the word “even” gives the sentence clear meaning, does adding it change the meaning??

> Larceny occurs even when the victim lacks the mental capacity to consent.

Comment: You mean "Even when larceny occurs the victim lacks the mental capacity to consent"? Because definitely not the same.

Comment: No Sir, you first response answered my question.  Thank you.  It was an answer on an exam and I was contemplating challenging it because the use of "even" changed the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The presence or absence of *even* certainly does change the meaning.

*Larceny occurs when...* suggests that what follows is the definition of larceny.

*Larceny occurs even when...* implies that the victim's lack of capacity might be expected to mean that the action was not larceny.

It's not clear what you mean by 'in the beginning'. Are you suggesting putting it right at the beginning of the sentence? If so, you would have to turn the whole sentence round for it to make sense.